# What is the expected number of runs of same color in a standard deck of cards?

Tags: probability, games

Standard deck has 52 cards, 26 Red and 26 Black. A run is a maximum contiguous block of cards, which has the same color.

Eg.

- (R,B,R,B,...,R,B) has 52 runs.
- (R,R,R,...,R,B,B,B,...,B) has 2 runs.

What is the expected number of runs in a shuffled deck of cards?

Comment: Apparently this has an easy solution.

Comment: Want to post it ?

Comment: why has this question/answer pair been imported _in toto_ from the math SE?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X_n$ denotes the color of the $n$th card in the shuffled deck.

Then note that the last card always denotes the end of a run. Other ends of runs are characterized by $X_n\ne X_{n+1}$ which indicates a run ending at $n$.

Note that $P(X_n\ne X_{n+1})=26/51$ (since once you fix a card, you can choose another card from remaining 51 out of which 26 will have a different color).

So summing up the indicators $X_n\ne X_{n+1}$ we get the number of runs -

$$\#\text{runs}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{51}\mathbb{I}_{X_n\ne X_{n+1}}.$$

So $$E(\#\text{runs})=1+\sum_{n=1}^{51}P(X_n\ne X_{n+1})=1+\sum_{n=1}^{51}26/51=27.$$

---

[Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2764/1074816)

Comment: I am not convinced -- is P(X_n != X_(n+1)) independent from n?

Comment: You ought to credit the person who *really* answered this question (George Lowther), especially because you copied his answer with only trivial changes.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/what-is-the-expected-number-of-runs-of-same-color-in-a-standard-deck-of-cards .

Comment: @whuber Yes definitely, it's not my credit. I merely reproduced it here. Thanks for putting up that note.
@Karsten It is shown by a counting argument - once you have fixed $X_n$ in 52 ways, there are 26 ways you can select non-matching $X_{n+1}$. So $P(X_n\ne X_{n+1})=\frac{52*26}{52*51}$.

Comment: @Karsten If you are asking if the events $X_n \ne X_{n+1}$ are independent of $n$, they are not. But that doesn't matter since expectation of sum = sum of expectations even if the quantities are dependent.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald–Wolfowitz_runs_test , where the mean number of runs matches that given here.